# Android Aidl enum not build

Tags: android, aidl

I'm trying to build my project, but always have problem with Aidl file
this is my Enum code

```
package com.example.printer;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Printer command status
 */
public enum PrinterCommandStatus implements Parcelable {
    /**
     * successful result
     */
    SUCCESS(1),
    /**
     * general error
     */
    ERROR(-1),
    /**
     * out of paper
     */
    OUT_OF_PAPER(123),
    /**
     * internal printer error
     */
    INTERNAL_ERROR(121),
    /**
     * printer over temperature
     */
    OVER_TEMPERATURE(75),
    /**
     * printer jammed paper
     */
    PAPERJAM(70),
    /**
     * printer voltage error
     */
    VOLTAGE_ERROR(55);

    private final int statuscode;

    PrinterCommandStatus(int statuscode) {
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<PrinterCommandStatus> CREATOR = new Creator<PrinterCommandStatus>() {
        @Override
        public PrinterCommandStatus createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return PrinterCommandStatus.valueOf(in.readString());
        }

        @Override
        public PrinterCommandStatus[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PrinterCommandStatus[size];
        }
    };

    public int getStatuscode() {
        return statuscode;
    }

    public static PrinterCommandStatus getPrinterCommandStatusByCode(int statuscode) {
        PrinterCommandStatus printerCommandStatus = ERROR;

        for (PrinterCommandStatus status : PrinterCommandStatus.values()) {
            if (status.getStatuscode() == statuscode) {
                printerCommandStatus = status;
                break;
            }
        }

        return printerCommandStatus;
    }
}
```

This is my Aidl

```
package com.example.printer;

import com.example.printer.PrinterCommandStatus;

interface IDirectPrintListener {

    void started( in String printId);

    void block( in String printId, in String reasonMessage, in com.example.printer.PrinterCommandStatus printerCommandStatus);

    void cancel( in String printId);

    void failed( in String printId, in String errorMessage, in com.example.printer.PrinterCommandStatus printerCommandStatus);

    void complete( in String printId);

}
```

When i'm add another class with **Parcelable**, all works fine, but it not work with enums, what i'm do wrong?
I'm try to rebuild project, but it doesn't work

Change in Aidl file enum to String and cast in to Enum not a good way, but i'm not found instruction how to do it correct with enum

Comment: Are you getting an error with enums ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I'm forgot add PrinterCommandStatus.aidl file with code

```
package com.example.printer;

parcelable PrinterCommandStatus;
```